# Java Matrix Transpose strangeness going on

Tags: java, class, matrix, copy, transpose

ok so im making my own Matrix class. and i have a transpose method that transposes a matrix. this is the block in the main method

```
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix(4,2);
    m1.fillMatrix(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
    System.out.println("before " + m1.toString());
    m1.transpose();
    System.out.println("after " + m1.toString());
```

this is where it gets messed up, at m1.transpose(); in the transpose() method

```
public Matrix transpose() {
    if(isMatrix2) {
        Matrix tempMatrix = new Matrix(row, col); // matrix2 contents are emptied once this line is executed
        for(int i=0; i < row; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < col; j++)
                tempMatrix.matrix2[i][j] = matrix2[i][j];
        }
```

so for some reason, the tempMatrix.matrix2 has the same id as this.matrix2. so when the codes executes

```
 Matrix tempMatrix = new Matrix(row,col);
```

then the contents of this.matrix2 is emptied. anyone know what might be going on here? the fields are all private static, if that helps...

Comment: What is `isMatrix2`?? And what is `matrix2`?

Comment: Can please you show the constructor for `Matrix`? I wonder if you're accidentally using static variables somewhere...

Comment: isMatrix2 is a boolean and matrix2 is a 2d array of ints... it doesnt matter what they are, its that something is happening to the contents of matrix2 when i dont touch it, or so i think. @ Paul, yes i mentioned in my op that all fields are declared as private static

Comment: thank you Paul, i changed all the fields so they are just private instead of private static. i dont understand why that would make a difference, but it did. it works fine now

Comment: @user1459976 If you declare a field `static` then all the instances that field. So, `matrix2` becomes common for all instances. So, when it becomes `empty` for tempMatrix, the change will be reflected to all instances.

Comment: oh right, that clears things right up. thanks for the explanation Rohit